# Mozilla CSS hack for text shadow

Tags: css, firefox

I am trying to create a text shadow in Mozilla browsers only. (I'm using this as a workaround for some issues with a font that I'm using.)

I have tried `-moz-text-shadow`, but it seems that this is now defunct and it no longer needs the moz extension. But I don't want Internet Explorer and WebKit to use the text shadow.

Why would the `-moz` function be taken away?

Comment: That's kind of an odd requirement. Could you explain why you wouldn't want other browsers to render the same? For me, I was always struggling to make all the browsers behave the same; I've never even considered making them behave differently on purpose (they do a lot of that very well all by themselves >.< )

Comment: because I'm working with font face and firefox has done the worst job at rendering the font. I have forced chrome to use svg and it looks great but the woff is looking awful in firefox.

Comment: Then that's likely a problem with the font, and not with Firefox. In my experience, Firefox and IE9 do best at rendering fonts on Windows.

Comment: -moz, -webkit, -o, -ms is called browser prefix. it used for browser that didn't support the property fully.

Comment: Once a new CSS property has been hashed out, the vendor prefix is dropped - that's the behaviour we want, which is why new versions of Firefox don't support the old prefixed version.

Comment: The current A List Apart has 2 good articles on vendor prefixes and why it's not "odd" that -moz- was taken away. Some recommended reading to learn a bit more about prefixes (particularly since one is an interview with Tantek, who works for Mozilla and the current hot topic about -moz- looking at supporting -webkit- for mobile FF) http://www.alistapart.com/issues/344

Comment: To be honest your correct about the font I'm using, it has some problems, but I was hoping for a work-around, failing that I'll be looking for a new font.

Comment: Fair enough I understand why we don't want prefixes generally, but sometimes there is good use for them. My understanding of css is limited, so I'm probably going about this the wrong way. Do you know of any way I can only use text-shadow in FF only or is it impossible? Will read that article now thanks.

Comment: Please don't use vendor prefixes to filter out browsers. It's what's pissing off the CSS working group, and on a more serious note, *hurting the Web*, right now.

Comment: Boltcock I don't know if your talking to me, but if I have to use vendor prefixes then I will whether it pisses the css working group or not. If it's available to use then I will use it.  And to be frank if there is no other way to make something work e.g border-radius, then I have to add -moz to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can target Firefox alone by using a CSS hack, such as:

```
body:not(:-moz-handler-blocked) a { background-color: red; }
```

Quick demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DxjeL/

The box should be red for Firefox and blue for all the other browsers.

This is from *[Browser CSS Hacks](http://paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks/)*.

Answer (score 1):

`-moz`, `-webkit`, `-o`, and `-ms` are called browser prefixes. They are used for browsers that didn't support the property fully.

And now every modern browser except Internet Explorer 8 and lower support the `text-shadow` property.

You can use JavaScript to detect the browser and add the text shadows property if you want to force adding a text shadow for just Firefox.

Comment: ok thanks, if this really is the only way then I'll skip it and just find some better fonts. Don't really want to use javascript for something like this. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Rough example:

```
text-shadow: 0 0 transparent;
-webkit-text-shadow: 0 0 transparent;
-khtml-text-shadow: 0 0 transparent;
-moz-text-shadow: 1px 1px #ff0000;
```

Comment: So are you saying I have to use text-shadow first if I want to use the moz only version too? I've tried -moz-text-shadow in a css class already, and it doesn't work, but when I drop the moz extension, it will work in all browsers, which isn't what I want.