# Text not showing in firefox

Tags: firefox

Everything was working fine in all browsers, but suddenly when i added an address in html files and gives that a style, Firefox not showing that text, however the rest of the text Firefox showing. I have tested this on other browsers like Chrome, Opera and IE10 and they all are showing that text.

You can see the screenshot here of how it is looking - https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIl0C.jpg

HTML:

```
<p class="addtitle">New York</p>
```

CSS:

```
.addtitle {
    padding-top:12px;
    margin-left:191px;
    font-family:'aleobold', sans-serif;
    font-size:30px;
    color:#fff;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    -moz-text-shadow: 0px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    -webkit-text-shadow: 0px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316230/moz-css-hack-for-text-shadow) is deprecated. If you have a look at Mozilla doc you will find that now you can directly use text-shadow ([doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-shadow))

This [article](http://maettig.com/code/css/text-shadow.html) links the change to Firefox 3.1

Hope this answer your question.

Comment: But.. shouldn't it just ignore the other prefixes if it supports the default?

Comment: As there is a moz- in the list my guess is that it tries this one.

Comment: And after testing in latest Firefox on OS X I would say that this is a bug in the version you are using as Mave is right, it should default to the non prefix and display properly.

Comment: @StephanePaquet: You are right. I have reinstalled the firefox completely and now the problem was solved. So i will choose your answer. Thanks mate.